# What is the correct if else statement for this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I want for this code to do is to perform the if action when there's a surf school/s already added and when the if condition is true. And I want to make a "Sorry, no surf school found" line when there's no surf school added yet.

Instead, this code will still show the else line even the if action is true.

```
<% @surfschools.each do |surfschool| %>
    <% if surfschool.surfschoolcountry == 'AX' %>
        <h3><%= link_to surfschool.surfschoolname, surfschool.surfschoolurl, target: '_blank' %></h3>
        <p>Country: <%= surfschool.surfschoolcountry %></p>
        <p>Address: <%= surfschool.surfschooladdress %></p>
        <p>Contact Number: <%= surfschool.surfschoolnumber %></p>
        <p>Contact E-mail: <%= surfschool.surfschoolemail %></p>
        <% if current_user && surfschool.user == current_user %>
            <%= link_to 'Update', edit_surfschool_path(surfschool) %>
            <%= link_to 'Delete', surfschool_path(surfschool), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
        <% end %>
     <% else %> 
       <p>Sorry, no surf school found</p> 
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Are you sure the condition is true? Try adding `<h2><%= surfschool.surfschoolcountry %></h2>` after the very first line.

Comment: You'll need to show the sample data as well; as shown, if the school's `surschoolcountry` is "AX" only the `if` statement will run. Unrelated, but prefixing all the field names with the class name seems really noisy, unless it's some sort of polymorphic thing added into models and it really needs to be there.

Comment: Just a suggestion, it is almost always better to follow the naming convention, especially if you are using ruby-on-rails.

Comment: @roob thanks but in which part of my code I don't follow a proper naming convention and I'll be happy to correct it the next time?

Comment: Cool :-) It's mostly that 'variable names' should use underscores. If SurfSchool is the class, then surf_school would be the instance and surf_schools would be the collection, and surf_school.surf_school_name would be the field( or instance method )

Comment: @roob I see. I'm aware of that and I just intentionally make surfschool as a one word :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're filtering on the country code of surf schools. As such, it would be much easier to just filter out the surf schools whose country code columns **aren't** `AX`.

```
#in the controller
@surfschools = SurfSchool.where(surfschoolcountry: "AX")

#in the view
<% if @surfschools.count == 0 %>
  <p>Sorry, no surf schools found</p>
<% else %>
  <!-- your code here -->
<% end %>
```

It's more straightforward this way, as well as data-driven.

Answer (score 0):

You can also include an image to lead the user somewhere else, for example:

```
<% if @surfschools.count == 0 %>
   <%= link_to image_tag("sorry.png"), root_path %>
```